# Could not run my C# program; getting the error "xxx.exe is not a valid win32 application"

Tags: c#, .net

The error is: "xxx.exe is not a valid win32 application"

this is a a c# program developed on my PC(x64), but the exe file didn't run on a x32 server

I went back in and change the build ---> configuration manager --> CPU but it still didn't work

Can anybody tell me how to make a win32 version of exe file?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What is the output type of the project you are trying to build?

Comment: trying to build a exe file to run on server side, in this case, either console app or windows app can work, any ideas?

Comment: There's a good idea below.  Why don't you check it out and see if it works?

Comment: @LifeScript can you please run `dumpbin /headers <myexecutable>.exe` on the server you are using to run the appliaction and post the results?  My suspicion is that even though you changed the CPU config, it didn't build a 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Microsoft .NET Framework is installed on the target system.

.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22

.NET Framework 4.5.1 download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779

Comment: Hmmm... is that the error you get when those are missing? (Not saying it's not... just dunno!)

Comment: But if it's a .exe file, all the OS can execute it regardless any .net platform right?

Comment: No, .NET exe's are interpreted by the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR), and cannot execute without having the CLR installed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Nope, you would see some sort of error denoting that you are missing the specific version of .Net to run the program.  His issue is definitely related to 32-bit vs. 64-bit runtimes.

Comment: @Evan I thought something like that; It's still a PE, but it just can't do much of anything without the .net runtime.